# Latest AWS Cloud Formation bootstrap binaries reported as not legit by VirusTotal?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

It seems the latest version of CloudFormation boostrap binaries used on EC2 Windows instances are reported as NOT legit by VirusTotal. Mainly cfn-elect-cmd-leader.exe" and "winhup.exe"

https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/a2f09c6a1f7d1f79bb7fd2a50424d11dcb606eafba4e5111e9f0ae772f576658/detection

Since such binaries are present by default in many EC2 instances type, this is going to generate a lot of alarms and blocked deployement. (Elastic Beanstalk is using them to spin new instances too).

So legit binaries or not ?

Comment: The question _may_ be better placed at https://security.stackexchange.com/ but I suspect contacting AWS may be even better.

Comment: Thanks @JoachimIsaksson, I will also report it there.